# Neo4j delete all nodes with a given label and their relationships in one query

Tags: neo4j

I separate my Neo4j database into isolated sub-databases using labels. During development, I frequently need to wipe an entire sub-database clean. Currently I do this with:

```
MATCH (n:myLabel)-[r]-() DELETE n, r
MATCH (n:myLabel) DELETE n
```

I need two queries because I have to delete all relationships, at the same time as their nodes, but I don't know how to match unconnected nodes simultaneously. Is there a way to wipe out a whole subgraph marked by a label in a single query? I'm on Neo4j 2.2.1

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

```
MATCH (n:myLabel) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r
```

Comment: This will not work : "Parentheses are required to identify nodes in patterns". Should be MATCH (n:myLabel) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r

Comment: Thanks, fixed!  I think that this was written before Neo4j started requiring that syntax :)